# Recreating a Dictionary from an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, ienumerable, idictionary

I have a method that returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ArrayList>>`, but some of the callers require the result of the method to be a dictionary. How can I convert the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ArrayList>>` into a `Dictionary<string, ArrayList>` so that I can use `TryGetValue`?

method:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ArrayList>> GetComponents()
{
  // ...
  yield return new KeyValuePair<string, ArrayList>(t.Name, controlInformation);
}
```

caller:

```
Dictionary<string, ArrayList> actual = target.GetComponents();
actual.ContainsKey("something");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850334/how-to-convert-ienumerable-of-keyvaluepairx-y-to-dictionary

Answer (score 382, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or .NET 4, it's easy to create the dictionary using LINQ:

```
Dictionary<string, ArrayList> result = target.GetComponents()
                                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

There's no such thing as an `IEnumerable<T1, T2>` but a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is fine.

Comment: You'd think there would be a call that doesn't require arguments, given that Dictionary<TKey, TValue> implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, but oh well.  Easy enough to make your own.

Comment: @emodendroket why would you think that? You can cast the Dictionary directly to the IEnumerable mentioned because of the interface, but not the other way around. i.e. `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` does not implement or inherit `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: @DanVerdolino I know that.  You'd think that because it's like one of the most common things you might want to do with an IEnumerable of KVPs.

Comment: 2016 now, and I still had to google this. You'd think that there would be a constructor for `Dictionary` that took a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` just like `List<T>` takes a `IEnumerable<T>`. Also there is no `AddRange` or even `Add` that takes key/value pairs. What's up with that?

Comment: It's 2017 now, and we can add this as an extension method!

Comment: A lot of "I can't believe .net core doesn't have <obvious feature>" is resolved via [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/).  Including a parameterless IEnumerable<KeyValuePair> -> `ToDictionary()`

Comment: `public static Dictionary<TKey,TValue> ToDictionary<TKey,TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> source) => source.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);` If you read this far and are still wanting, here is this answer as an extension method.

Answer (score 32):

As of .NET Core 2.0, the constructor [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netcore-2.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair__0__1___) now exists.