# Comparing Two Lists

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having 2 lists. I should compare the 2 lists and should take the common value from both the list and i should put it in a string array...

First List....

```
List<string> IDs = new List<string>();
Dictionary<string, Test> group = TestProxy.GetNames(IDs.ToArray());
```

Second List...

```
List<string> Names = new List<string>();
Dictionary<string, Test> groupNames = TestProxy.GetSections(Names.ToArray());
```

How to take the common values...

Updated code....

```
        List<string> IDs = new List<string>();
        modulesIDs.Add("ID1");
        Dictionary<string, Group> group = PrivilegeProxy.GetNames(IDs.ToArray());

        List<string> Roles = new List<string>();
        Roles.Add("Role1");
        Dictionary<string, Role> Role = PrivilegeProxy.GetRoles(Roles.ToArray());


        Dictionary<string, "******"> common = group.Intersect(Role).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        return common;
```

In the "common" Dictionary which object should i give ( " Dictionary common" )

Comment: whoa pal.. this changed the whole scope of the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) and [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx)

```
    Dictionary<string, Test> commonGroups = group.Intersect(groupNames)
        .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Update: Read this if doubt persists. [Recreating a Dictionary from an IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2636603/17447)

Comment: what should i give in ...x=>x.Key, x => x.Value

Comment: no need to change anything. just use the code as is. get back if you have an error