# How to convert IEnumerable of KeyValuePair<x, y> to Dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Is there streamlined way to convert list/enumberable of `KeyValuePair<T, U>` to `Dictionary<T, U>`?

Linq transformation, .ToDictionary() extension did not work.

Comment: When you say *it didn't work,* **what** didn't work? Couldn't compile? Didn't return the output you expected? Exception?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636603/recreating-a-dictionary-from-an-ienumerable) post Similar Question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recreating a Dictionary from an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636603/recreating-a-dictionary-from-an-ienumerablekeyvaluepair)

Comment: @nvoigt It's basically the same topic. Maybe less noisy and  more to the point on this thread.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
.ToDictionary(kvp=>kvp.Key,kvp=>kvp.Value);
```

Isn't that much more work.

Comment: Shame there's no cleaner way of doing it, but it'll do!

Answer (score 13):

You can create your own extension method that would perform as you expect.

```
public static class KeyValuePairEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source)
    {
        return source.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I could produce:

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> keyValuePairs)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    var dictAsIDictionary = (IDictionary<TKey, TValue>) dict;
    foreach (var property in keyValuePairs)
    {
        (dictAsIDictionary).Add(property);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

I compared the speed of converting an IEnumerable of 20 million key value pairs to a Dictionary using Linq.ToDictionary with the speed of this one. This one ran in 80% of the time of the Linq version. So it's faster, but not a lot. I think you'd really need to value that 20% saving to make it worth using.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the others, but using `new` instead of `ToDictionary` (since `new` *already* supports `KeyValuePair` enumerations) and allowing the passing of an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`.

Also including a `ToReadOnlyDictionary` variant for completeness.

```
public static class EnumerableKeyValuePairExtensions {

    public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> keyValuePairs, IEqualityComparer<TKey>? comparer = null)
    where TKey : notnull
        => new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(keyValuePairs, comparer);

    public static ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> keyValuePairs, IEqualityComparer<TKey>? comparer = null)
    where TKey : notnull
        => new ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>(keyValuePairs.ToDictionary(comparer));
}
```