# Keep Where() consistent for Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recreating a Dictionary from an IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636603/recreating-a-dictionary-from-an-ienumerable)

When using the Where method on a dictionary of type `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you ends up with a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TSource>>` and that is breaking the datatype that I have choose at the beginning. I would like to return a dictionary.

Maybe I am not using the correct filter function. So how do you usually filter element from a dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting to get when filtering the dictionary ? values or keys?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2636628/1004522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) actually extends `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.  This is why you can use LINQ operators on an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` in the first place.

However, LINQ operators return [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) which are meant to provide [*deferred* execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx), meaning the results aren't actually generated until you start iterating through the `IEnumerable<T>`.

The `IEnumerable<T>` implementation which is provided by `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` comes by way of the [`ICollection<T>` interface](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFcQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx&ei=oKXpT-KLB8aJ6AGI-vmFDQ&usg=AFQjCNH9Rx-AertMm5Z70BoXDKVKjEf7zg&sig2=Y6IFSyLWz1pN1IuQZlZ_cw) (where `T` is a [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)), which means that if LINQ were to return `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead of `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` then it would have to materialize the list, violating it's principals (hence the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` return value).

Of course, the way around it is to call the `ToDictionary` extension method on the `Enumerable class` (as others have mentioned), but a little back-story never hurts.

Comment: IMHO it is not a good idea to have dictionary "inherit" all the LINQ query especially that deferred execution is not an interesting feature to have for a dictionary. A cleaner API with proper method that accept closure would have been better.

Comment: @mathk It's not really an issue with the dictionary, but the fact that it implements `ICollection<T>`; what you're suggesting is that anything that implements `ICollection<T>` would materialize it's result set after *each* operation.  That's *highly* inefficient as you'd have to materialize the `ICollection<T>` after *each* query operation (*every* `select`, `where`, `let`, etc.).

Comment: It is not what I am saying. I am saying the it should not inherit all LINQ qyuery. It does not make a lot of sens to have query operation on dictionary. Especially that query expression are lazy evaluated and that is not as pretty as the Haskell lazy evaluation.

Comment: @mathk I see what you're saying, but then you'd either have to a) remove the `ICollection<T>` implementation from `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` (which doesn't make much sense) or b) find a way to tell type inference to not be used for specific derivations of a type.  Either proposition isn't too appealing, IMO.

Comment: Yes, I concider that the Dictionary API is not well implemented I rather have Dictionary implement an interface like: `interface IDctionary<TKey, TValue>
    {
        Dictionary<TKey, TResult> Collect<TResult>(Func<TKey, TValue, TResult> collector);
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Reject(Func<TKey, TValue, Boolean> predicate);
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Select(Func<TKey, TValue, Boolean> predicate); // The correct meaning of select
        void Do(Func<TKey, TValue> block);
        ...
    }`

Comment: Seeing that the method `.ToDictionary()` have been implemented seems a big bodgy smell. Dictionary shouldn't have implement the ICollection at the first place. Or the IEnumerable part of ICollection

Answer (score 1):

How about `.ToDictionary()` in the end?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Where()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx), and follow with [ToDictionary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx):

```
var newDict = yourDict.Where(pair => SomePredicateFrom(pair))
                      .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Comment: I usually avoid To*() method. Especially this one who take 2 lambda. It sound like I am using a sword for cutting the bread. But if the API force me to do it that way, I have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.ToDictionary();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) in your LINQ expression.