# difference between IEnumerable vs Dictionary C#

Tags: c#

If you go to [this link in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636603/recreating-a-dictionary-from-an-ienumerablekeyvaluepair). There is a question about converting an Ienrumerable to Dictionary.  So my question is why would we need IEnumerable when we have the dictionary object?

Actually, i am trying to figure out what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 5):

`IEnumerable` is an `interface`. An interface can not be instantiated by itself, but have to be instantiated as a class that implements the given interface.

`Dictionary` is a `hash-map` datastructure that implements the `IEnumerable` interface, hence it have all the methods and properties that the `IEnumerable` interface requires its implementations to have, making it possible to `Enumerate` the Dictionary structure.

*In short: IEnumerable is an interface and Dictionary is a class implementing the interface.*

Comment: Yes so that is what I mean you use interface to create classes  and and IEnumerable is an interface not a class. And that interface is implemented by a Dictionary.  So since Dictionary is uses IEnumerable why wouldnt someone just return Dictionary object.   Anyway, i must be missing something I am into my studies now so I can start to get some sense.

Comment: The IEnumerable inheritage pretty much only promise that the object is possible to iterate. A Dictionary is always IEnumberable, a IEnumerable object is not always a Dictionary.

Comment: Thnaks Jite for explanation, but what I am saying. IEnumerable is an interface. And if i read the definition of interface it says interfaces are implemented in other classes and their members must be defined in called class. If i follow the definition then I am so confused by which principle I can directly assign values to an interface.   Anyway it is my last post in this topic thanks.

Comment: @Jite this was a great edit. I am glad to see someone actually answered the question asked instead of insulting the asker, like many others who left comments/answers on this question

Answer (score 2):

well, the question you've linked is on the opposite question. how to convert from `IEnumerable` to a `Dictionary`. why will we convert the other way around? we will probably won't. but you can also ask why will someone convert a specific class to object?

the answer is the sometimes you want to have a variable/method parameter/ class member that can be one of many things: a dictionary or something else. for that you might use `IEnumerable`.

Comment: "convert a specific class to object" o_O

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is why would we need IEnumerable when we have the dictionary object?

The question you've referred is about opposite: creating `Dictionary` **from** `IEnumerable`. So you have `IEnumerable` and you'd like to have `Dictionary`.

It can be required when you have e.g. e `List` and you'd like to have quicker access to collection elements by one of the items property value.

And just to be sure, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` already implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so the conversion would not necessary in the opposite direction (unless you're trying to change the `T`).

Comment: Sorry guys I am trying to learn. I was reading about Generics objects and it says Dictionary and all Generics objects uses IEnumerable interface.         I am not really clear with the answers due to lack of my knowledge but i will check back after some more readings.